# Transform manager error with large files only

Tags: iis-7, transformation, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I'm using IIS Transform Manager to transcode my .ISMV files. All the configuration is working file with small size files like 100 MB, 400 MB.. etc

But when I try to transcode **1.36 GB** file, I'm getting following error (I'm using **VC-1 IIS Smooth Streaming - 720p CBR.xml** preset for transcoding):

```
2013-10-08 14:56:39.1952  Information Machine name: SSMINGEST1
```

2013-10-08 14:56:39.1952  Information Task engine process ID: 3896
2013-10-08 14:56:39.1952  Information Instance file name: Encoder1.ismv
2013-10-08 14:56:39.1952  Information Creating output folder: C:\inetpub\media\Transform Manager\Smooth (VC1)\WorkQueue\Running\111111111111111111111111111\EE4Output
2013-10-08 14:56:53.5424  Information Task C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Transform Manager\Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.EE40SP2Task.dll file version 7.1.1565.4.
2013-10-08 14:57:04.5957  Information Preset file from preset property: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IIS\Transform Manager\Configuration\Presets\VC-1 IIS Smooth Streaming - 720p CBR.xml.
2013-10-08 14:57:04.6113  Information Template from templateName property: Standard.
2013-10-08 14:57:04.6113  Information Template path from templatePath property: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Expression\Encoder 4\Templates\en\Standard.
2013-10-08 14:57:04.7830  Audit       SSMINGEST1\brian Expression Encoder task transforming file C:\inetpub\media\Transform Manager\Smooth (VC1)\WorkQueue\Running\11111111111111111111111111111\Encoder1.ismv.
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8126  Error          at Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.MediaImportInfo.OpenAndValidateMediaFile(String strFilename, MediaLoadOptions loadOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.EETask.CreateMediaItems(IEnumerable`1 inputFiles, String preset)
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8126  Error       An unknown error has occurred
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error       Task.Initialize failed for task index 1.
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error       Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.InvalidMediaFileException: An unknown error has occurred
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error          at Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.MediaImportInfo.OpenAndValidateMediaFile(String strFilename, MediaLoadOptions loadOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.EETask.CreateMediaItems(IEnumerable`1 inputFiles, String preset)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.EETask.AssignJobParameters()
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.EETask.Initialize(ITaskStatus status, IJobMetadata metadata, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.Wrapper.RunTaskCode(TaskStatus taskStatus, JobMetadata metadata, Logger logger, ITask task, Int32 taskIndex)
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error       Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.UnableToAnalyzeFileException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error          at MS.Internal.Expression.Encoder.Media.MediaFileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
   at MS.Internal.Expression.Encoder.MediaImport.MediaInfoCache`1.CreateMediaFileInfoFromFile(String strFilename)
   at MS.Internal.Expression.Encoder.MediaImport.MediaInfoCache`1.OpenMediaFileInfo(String strFilename)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.MediaImportInfo.OpenMediaFileInfo(String strFilename)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.MediaImportInfo.OpenAndValidateMediaFile(String strFilename, MediaLoadOptions loadOptions)
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error       System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error          at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at ThrowHRESULT(Int32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.Expression.Encoder.Media.MediaFileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Error       Exiting task. Task ID: 1
2013-10-08 14:57:06.8282  Information UpdateStatus message: An unknown error has occurred

Please help me.

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and I did following steps:

1) Uninstall Transform Manager.

2) Download Expression Encoder SP2 setup from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27870) and install it. Please remember don't uninstall the previous one. This will update the previously installed copy.

3) Now try transcoding.

I hope this will help you.